# how to interpret keyeventargs in windows8 consumer preview

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

There seems to be some changes in the Windows 8 consumer preview with regards to `KeyEventArgs`. What is the best way to interpret `KeyEventArgs` and tell what key was pressed or released? I am guessing I need to map the Key (of type `VirtualKey`) property to the actualy ascii code (I am happy with ascii and not worry about unicode and other keyboard layout). Is there an easier way to manage shift/control and other combined keystrokes?

Answer (score 0):

Does `KeyboardEvent` work for you?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465793.aspx

UPDATE:

This is only for `Javascript`.

Leaving this there in case any future ones is looking for this.

Comment: I am using C#/xaml and not html/css. I am not sure how to do it in C#.

Comment: KeyboardEvent is for use in javascript

Comment: Yes. It is. I guess you must have checked this then. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br208911.aspx

Comment: yup, my problem is that KEyEventArgs that is sent with the callbacks do not seem to have a clear way of converting to a character.